# React Carbon Dynamic Content Switcher Doesn't Accept Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carbon-design-system

I am trying to pass some api data to the react carbon component. When i use a static switcher inside the content switcher, it works perfectly, but when i use a dynamic one, i seem to have some missing props on my onClick function. I cannot establish why and i can't seem to find anything on the documentation. Any help/ recommendations on what im doing wrong will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<ContentSwitcher
   size="sm"
   selectedIndex={1}
   className={styles.prioritySwitcher}
   onChange={(event) => {
     setPriority(event.name as any);
   }}>
  {mockPriorities.data.map((priority) => {
     <Switch name={priority.uuid} text={priority.display} />})}
</ContentSwitcher>
```

This has `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'props')` error :

```
<ContentSwitcher
    size="sm"
    className={styles.prioritySwitcher}
    onChange={(event) => setPriority(event.name as any)}>
    <Switch name={priorityType.NOT_URGENT} text={t('notUrgent', 'Not Urgent')} value={priority} />
    <Switch name={priorityType.PRIORITY} text={t('priority', 'Priority')} value={priority} />
    <Switch name={priorityType.EMERGENCY} text={t('emergency', 'Emergency')} value={priority} /></ContentSwitcher> */}
```

My mock data looks like this :

```
export const mockPriorities = {
  data: [
    {
      display: 'Urgent',
      uuid: 'c81e4576-18c9-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      display: 'Not Urgent',
      uuid: 'ce281be0-18c9-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      display: 'Emergency',
      uuid: 'd504169e-18c9-11ed-861d-0242ac120002',
      id: 3,
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a return statement like this and it work :

```
<ContentSwitcher
   size="sm"
   selectedIndex={1}
   className={styles.prioritySwitcher}
   onChange={(event) => {
     setPriority(event.name as any);
   }}>
  {mockPriorities.data.map((priority) => {
     return <Switch name={priority.uuid} text={priority.display} />})}
</ContentSwitcher>
```